# Magento 2 - How to find all products with Salable qty as 0 via SQL query?

Tags: magento2, product, sql, quantity, salable

Is there a simple SQL query I can run to find any ***ENABLED*** product in Magento that has a salable quantity which is 0?

We have thousands of products and in the back end product grid we can sort and range by Quantity, don't have the ability to filter or sort but via Salable Quantity column which is super frustrating, and there is many inaccuracies we are trying to resolve and its very time consuming to go through page after page in the grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query which will return the enabled products having 0 salable quantity.

```
SELECT t1.`sku`, (SUM(t1.`quantity`) + COALESCE(SUM(t2.`quantity`), 0)) AS `salable_quantity` FROM `inventory_source_item` t1 LEFT JOIN `inventory_reservation` t2 ON t1.`sku` = t2.`sku` AND t1.`status` = 1 GROUP BY t1.`sku` HAVING `salable_quantity` = 0 AND t1.`sku` NOT IN (SELECT `sku` FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `row_id` IN (SELECT `row_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id` = (SELECT `attribute_id`  FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'status' AND `entity_type_id` = 4) AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 2));
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you 

Comment: Your welcome! Can you please accept this as answer and up-vote it. Thanks!

Comment: Would love to up-vote but i'm new and don't have enough reputation to action. If you can up-vote my question, i'll be sure to return in kind once my reputation score allows me to!